# Error at inserting in sql

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I have created some variables and I want to insert them into a database, I used a for loop to insert some values in array but I got that this error

> Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@finalwords".

Here it is my code

```
string []finalwords=new string[13000];

for (int h=0;h<wordsbeforesoundex.Length;h++)
{
   if (wordsbeforesoundex[h] == "")
      continue;

   finalwords[indexer] = wordsbeforesoundex[h];
   indexer++;
}

for (int l = 0; l < words.Length; l++)
{
   con.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableFFF (Data) VALUES (@finalwords[l])", con);

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@finalwords[l]", finalwords[l]));

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that SQL supports indexing operators on arguments (`@finalwords[l]`)? I would just use `@finalwords` as a parameter name.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather change it like

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableFFF (Data) VALUES (@finalwords_idx)", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@finalwords_idx", finalwords[l]));
```

Answer (score -1):

your insert query is not proper, change the query

```
"INSERT INTO TableFFF (Data) VALUES (@finalwords["+l+"])"
```

Comment: What is your table structure and what u try to add in it.because @ variable not declare in array.. Please put your table query too.